# Python diff very large files

Tags: python, diff

I have sufficient large file that will not fit in memory, so doing a `diff filea fileb > mydiff.txt` is not an option on a UNIX shell. Also I need to set a crontab to do it daily and insert the different lines into a database using Python 2.x

I could do something like:

```
with ('fileb'm 'rb').readlines() as fileb:
    with open('filea', 'rb') as filea:
        for line in filea:
            if line not in fileb:
                yield line
```

But this is 1) slow and 2) most likely to not fit in memory too.

Is there a quick, pythonic way of doing kinda a `diff` for this case?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2150/diffing-two-big-text-files

Comment: Why are you using the `with` syntax for one file but not the other?

Comment: `readlines()` reads in the whole file. What you want is `readline()` which reads line by line.